# ADF Mobile How to use VideoCapturePlus plugin or any video recorder plugin

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile, oracle-maf

I'm using adf mobile to record video ,

i search for that and i find plugins to do that like VideoCapturePlus

but i don't know how to use it

can any body help me

Comment: Which one are you using: ADF Mobile or Oracle MAF?

Comment: i'm using ADF Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIDemo Its application example from oracle

its have video recorder